# SQL Legacy Joins

Tags: sql, t-sql, syntax, outer-join

I'm looking at some of the older SQL code and I'm wondering what would be the proper way to convert this batch into current SQL syntax. I appreciate your help.

```
    If @Type = 'Edit'  
    Begin
        If @Area = 'Box'
            Declare CursorInv Cursor For 
                Select Retention_Code, 
                    Company_Id, 
                    Department_Id, 
                    Group_Id, 
                    Section_Id, 
                    Locator_Id, 
                    Location_Current, 
                    Location_Home, 
                    Box_User_Defined1.Udf_Code User_Defined1, 
                    Box_User_Defined2.Udf_Code User_Defined2, 
                    Box_User_Defined3.Udf_Code User_Defined3
        From Box, Box_User_Defined1, Box_User_Defined2, Box_User_Defined3
        Where Box_Number = @KeyValue And 
                Box.User_Defined1 *= Box_User_Defined1.ID And 
                Box.User_Defined2 *= Box_User_Defined2.ID And 
                Box.User_Defined3 *= Box_User_Defined3.ID
```

Comment: Tip: This might be a good time to add aliases to all of the columns, e.g. `select B.RetentionCode, ... from Box as B inner join Box_User_Defined1 as BUD1 on B.User_Defined1 = BUD1.Id ...`. It makes the sources of the columns clearer which is a good thing for maintenance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*=` joins pretty much translate to `LEFT JOIN` in newer syntax:

```
SELECT Retention_Code, 
    Company_Id, 
    Department_Id, 
    Group_Id, 
    Section_Id, 
    Locator_Id, 
    Location_Current, 
    Location_Home, 
    Box_User_Defined1.Udf_Code User_Defined1, 
    Box_User_Defined2.Udf_Code User_Defined2, 
    Box_User_Defined3.Udf_Code User_Defined3
FROM Box
LEFT JOIN Box_User_Defined1 ON Box.User_Defined1 = Box_User_Defined1.ID
LEFT JOIN Box_User_Defined2 ON Box.User_Defined2 = Box_User_Defined2.ID
LEFT JOIN Box_User_Defined3 ON Box.User_Defined3 = Box_User_Defined3.ID
WHERE Box_Number = @KeyValue
```